# Clicking on Child components without firing clicked event on parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I have an angular based appication (currently v4.4). I have a view where a component displays an instance of itself for a finite number of times and then in the lowest "child" component, there is an svg.

I want to be able to pickup the lowest component that has been clicked using the `(click)` event. I thought that I might be able to setup the z-index to link to the iteration number so that each subsequent child component appears on top of it's parent, so when anywhere in that area is clicked, the correct event is fired.

I have made this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aUxEKKvcFCHwQcD327SC?p=preview) on plunkr. You will see that clicking on the svg does not fire the clicked event, but clicking on any other area inside the boxes, causes the clicked event for that box and all it's parents.

I would like to be able to toggle all boxes abckground colors independantly.

Here are the components I have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <my-child [iteration]="0"></my-child>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `
    <div class="border" [style.background]="toggle ? 'green' : 'pink'" (click)="clicked()">
    {{iteration}}
      <my-child [iteration]="iteration" *ngIf="iteration < 3"></my-child>
      <object *ngIf="iteration == 3" 
      id="img" width="300" height="300"
      data="http://snapsvg.io/assets/images/logo.svg"></object>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Child {
  name:string;
  @Input() iteration;
  toggle: boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
    this.toggle = false;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    ++this.iteration;
  }
  clicked(){
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    console.log(this.iteration)
  }
}
```

## UPDATE:

The current answers answer the first part of this question, but don't deal with the svg click not firing the click event for the component that displays the svg.

Comment: did you tried css solutions? `pointer-events` of parent can be `none` when you want only child event trigger.

Comment: @EmadEmami I would like an angular event fired, because I ultimately want to use the iteration value of the clicked component to be used for navigation

Answer (score 5):

I succeed to did it in your plunker. You have to use event.stopPropagation() at the top of your cliked function, but you also have to add the $event in your click action, like this :

in your html you must have

```
(click)=clicked($event)
```

in your.ts add your stopPropagation :

```
clicked(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

**EDIT :** 
The solution for your last layer, using an invisible div on top of the svg element, you might need to adapt the style or position.

```
<div style="width:300px; height:300px; position:absolute; z-index:1000">
</div>
<object *ngIf="iteration == 3" 
      id="img" width="300" height="300"
      data="http://snapsvg.io/assets/images/logo.svg">
</object>
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves most of the issue, but I am still faced with clicking on the svg not registering a click on child component 3 (the component which contains the svg) - see this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/uAJ2QOzM4rzYtBd5DoVX?p=preview) with your modifications

Comment: Yes, I can see you can't click on the svg, if you want to do that you have two possibilites : add a click listener on your DOM element using ElementRef, then get your svg element using <object #domAccess> or using id. 
The other posibility is to add a 300px x 300px div in absolute position just before your object : <div style="width:300px; height:300px; position:absolute; z-index:1000"></div><object...

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

`event.stopPropagation();` at the top of the child element's click handler.  You may need to add this to other event handlers for mousedup/down ect.

Also you could try css:
  `#parentElement {  pointer-events: none;  }` on the parent, and
  `.childElement  {  pointer-events: auto;  }` on the child elements;

and add the id and class name to the parent and children respectively.

Comment: The answer is not entirely good, use my answer instead with the $event params in your click actions ;)

Comment: If you put the stopPropagation in the existing click handler, you dont need to create an extra handler..

Comment: I am still faced with clicking on the svg not registering a click on child component 3 (the component which contains the svg)?